# How to add target_link_directories to dlls in cmake?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, cmake

I have 3 dll's with the same name debug/alpha.dll, release/alpha.dll and relwithdebinfo/alpha.dll

I want to get cmake to do this:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} debug ../adir/debug/alpha.dll)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} relwithdebinfo ../adir/relwithdebug/alpha.dll)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} release ../adir/release/alpha.dll)
```

This I would think would add those three different dll's depending on what configuration is specified in visual studio 2015.

It ALMOST works, it tries to load:

```
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file '../adir/debug/alpha.lib'
```

QUESTION: HOW do I get it to substitute DLL for the LIB it put there, I just want it to stop ASSuming lib, and actually listen to what I put, .dll and everything will work great.

Any way to get it to stop helping out so much?  Anyone know another way to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: ***HOW do I get it to substitute DLL for the LIB it put there, I just want it to stop ASSuming lib, and actually listen to what I put, .dll and everything will work great.*** Why do you want to link to dlls? With dlls you link to an import library with a `.lib` extension not the dll itself.

Comment: I cannot be the only person who has 2 projects, one which makes a DLL, one which makes an exe which depends on that dll...and wants to run in debug mode. I mean, thats it! I just want to be able to run my exe in release or debug and have the RIGHT dll used when its run, am I all alone in the world in wanting something so hugely complex???

Comment: ***I cannot be the only person who has 2 projects, one which makes a DLL, one which makes an exe which depends on that dll..*** You are not. I use dlls all the time with Visual Studio and CMake. If you export symbols from your dill using the proper `__declspec(dllexport)` (usually done by a macro since you need that to change to `__declspec(dllimport)`for code that uses the dll) an import library will be created. You link to that and during runtime the dll will be loaded (provided it is in the search path).

Answer (score 1):

In your original question you asked how to `target_link_libraries` with a `.dll` file. `target_link_libraries` requires a `.lib`.

### Hacky, tricky and maybe impossible solution

```
SET(ENGINE_LIBRARY optimized "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../mylib.lib" debug "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../mylib_d.lib")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${ENGINE_LIBRARY})
```

You may use any of [CMake useful variables](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables) (`${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}`, for example) to specify `.lib` file path. Moreover, you'll need to `add_dependencies(myproj mylib)` to insure that `.exe` file will not be linked before `.lib` and `.dll` files are generated.
Moreover, to run output project with Visual Studio, you'll need both `.dll` and `.exe` files to be in the same folder, and CMake does not provide this by default. There's a hacky function like one below to set one and only directory for all output files (You'll need to modify it if you want to support different builds - I mean debug/release/etc... - but I'm not sure that's possible).

```
#set output directory for all subprojects

set (outputdirectory "../../../__test_environment")
# First for the generic no-config case (e.g. with mingw)
set( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${outputdirectory} )
set( CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${outputdirectory} )
set( CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${outputdirectory} )
# Second, for multi-config builds (e.g. msvc)
foreach( OUTPUTCONFIG ${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES} )
    string( TOUPPER ${OUTPUTCONFIG} OUTPUTCONFIG )
    set( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} ${outputdirectory} )
    set( CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} ${outputdirectory} )
    set( CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} ${outputdirectory} )
endforeach( OUTPUTCONFIG CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES )
```

### The solution that CMake provides out of the box (recommended)

The key point here is to use `install` CMake statement.

Let's examine sample project with this folder structure

```
mylib/CMakeLists.txt
mylib/mylib.cpp
mylib/mylib.hpp
CMakeLists.txt
myproj.cpp
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(myproj)

set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS TRUE)

if (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
    add_definitions(-D MYPROJ_DLL)
endif()

add_subdirectory(mylib)

set(HEADERS
    mylib/mylib.hpp
)

set(SOURCES
    myproj.cpp
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} mylib)

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION .)
```

mylib/CMakeLists.txt

```
project(mylib)

set(HEADERS
    mylib.hpp
)

set(SOURCES
    mylib.cpp
)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES})

if (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
    install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION .)
endif()
```

mylib/mylib.cpp

```
#include "mylib.hpp"

int MYLIB_API mysum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

mylib/mylib.hpp

```
#pragma once

#ifdef MYPROJ_DLL
#   ifdef _WINDLL
#       define MYLIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#   else
#       define MYLIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#   endif
#else
#   define MYLIB_API
#endif

int MYLIB_API mysum(int a, int b);
```

myproj.cpp

```
#include "mylib/mylib.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("%d\n", mysum(5, 6));
    return 0;
}
```

With `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` set to `TRUE` you will build `SHARED` libraries, with it set to `FALSE` you'll build `STATIC` libraries.
Tricky things about this solution are that you'll need

- to manually create `C:\Program Files (x86)\myproj` folder and give yourself full control under it (see mouse right click -> Properties -> Security tab)
- to set to run `C:\Program Files (x86)\myproj\myproj.exe` file to run in Visual Studio
- to compile `INSTALL` project in Visual Studio (or set it as Startup Project and properly setup debugging for it).

Thus every time you'll build `INSTALL` project all of your binary files in it will appear in `C:\Program Files (x86)\myproj\myproj.exe`

## The most recommended solution

If you develop only in Visual Studio - do not use CMake. Every tool needs to be used wisely.

Comment: I cannot be the only person who has 2 projects, one which makes a DLL, one which makes an exe which depends on that dll...and wants to run in debug mode.  I mean, thats it!  I just want to be able to run my exe in release or debug and have the RIGHT dll used when its run, am I all alone in the world in wanting something so hugely complex???

Comment: @user2016641 because of misunderstanding added 3 ways to solve this problem I tried myself.

Answer (score 1):

To be more precise, you can't link a .dll file with visual studio compiler (nor any other compiler on windows). That's not a cmake issue. Where did you get your alpha.dll in the first place? Did you compile it?

Comment: Ok, not link, obviously, dynamic has a meaning....it DLL dynamic link library, so yes, they end up LINKED DYNAMICALLY...  The dll is generated by one of my projects, the main exe needs obviously to reference the properly built version of the dll, the debug/release depending.  So, I want VS, when it runs my main exe, to be able to find the correct version of the dll...I hope this is clear

Comment: What you have to do is either to build your library as a static library, or to generate an import library when building your dll (see [here](http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake/2008-August/023194.html)). You can also use a new mechanism provided by cmake (see [here](https://blog.kitware.com/create-dlls-on-windows-without-declspec-using-new-cmake-export-all-feature/)). I didn't try it myself so I don't know how efficient it is

Comment: The links lack linux/unix support. Tell me if you need it